# Managing a wish list from an API

Tags: ios, swift, delegates, protocols

I have a class that I use to manage a list to/from an API in Swift. Using a [clean code](https://sites.google.com/site/unclebobconsultingllc/) approach, I'm wondering if, how, and why I should change it when I have a class that uses it for just one or two functions.

Here's the class:

```
import Foundation

protocol ApiWishListManagerDelegate
{
    func didFailWishList(failError: NSError?)
    func didGetWishList()
    func didAddToWishList()
    func didUpdate()
    func didDelete()
}

class ApiMyAccountWishListManager: ApiController
{
    // MARK: - Vars
    var delegateWishList: ApiWishListManagerDelegate?

    // MARK: - Inits

    override init()
    {
        super.init()
    }

    init(delegateWishList: ApiWishListManagerDelegate)
    {
        super.init()
        self.delegateWishList = delegateWishList
    }

    // MARK: - Functions

    func addToWishList(productId: Int)
    {
        var dataToPost = NSDictionary(objects: [productId], forKeys: ["pid"])
        post(MakeURL.addToWishList(), postData: dataToPost, callBack: parseAddToWishList)
    }

    func parseAddToWishList(data: NSData?, response: NSURLResponse, error: NSError?)
    {
        if let jsonResultDictionary = convertOnSuccessAPI(response, data: data!)
        {
            self.delegateWishList!.didAddToWishList()
            return
        }
        self.delegateWishList!.didFailWishList(error)
    }

    func readItems()
    {
        get(MakeURL.getWishList(), queryString: "", https: true, callBack: parseReadItems)
    }

    func parseReadItems(data: NSData?, response: NSURLResponse, error: NSError?)
    {
        if let jsonResultDictionary = convertOnSuccessAPI(response, data: data!)
        {
            MyAccountDataCache.sharedInstance.saveWishList(jsonResultDictionary)
            self.delegateWishList!.didGetWishList()
            return
        }
        self.delegateWishList!.didFailWishList(error)
    }

    func updateItemQuantity(productId: Int, quantity: Int, folderId: Int)
    {
        var dataToPost = NSDictionary(objects: [productId, quantity, folderId], forKeys: ["pid", "prodQty", "srcFolderID"])
        post(MakeURL.chageQuantity(), postData: dataToPost, callBack: parseUpdateItemQuantity)
    }

    func parseUpdateItemQuantity(data: NSData?, response: NSURLResponse, error: NSError?)
    {
        if wasCallSuccessfulAPI(response) && data?.length == 0
        {
            self.delegateWishList!.didUpdate()
            return
        }
        self.delegateWishList!.didFailWishList(error)
    }

    func deleteItemFromFolder(productId: Int, folderId: Int = 0)
    {
        var dataToPost = NSDictionary(objects: [productId, folderId], forKeys: ["pid", "srcFolderID"])
        put(MakeURL.removeProduct(), postData: dataToPost, queryString: "", callBack: parseDeleteItemFromFolder)
    }

    func parseDeleteItemFromFolder(data: NSData?, response: NSURLResponse, error: NSError?)
    {
        if let jsonResultDictionary = convertOnSuccessAPI(response, data: data!)
        {
            self.delegateWishList!.didDelete()
            return
        }
        self.delegateWishList!.didFailWishList(error)
    }
}
```

The main question is when a class is using this manager, for something like just getting the wishlist, we have a set of empty delegates like this:

```
    // MARK: - ApiWishListManager

    func didFailWishList(failError: NSError?)
    {
        hideSpinner()
    }

    func didGetWishList()
    {
        mainTableView.reloadData()
        hideSpinner()
    }

    func didAddToWishList()
    {
    }

    func didUpdate()
    {
    }

    func didDelete()
    {
    }
```

The add, update and delete are just sitting there never to be used.  I know about making them optional, using @objc, but I don't really want to add all the extra code that goes with checking if the delegate is setup before calling each one.  I've tried adding delegates within the same class, but I think that just starts looking too ugly and makes extra code for the classes that need all of the functions of this one manager.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We should definitely go ahead and use `@objc` and make the methods optional that make sense to be optional.

In Swift, it's actually not nearly as bad to check whether or not a delegate is set up or responds to a selector.  In Objective-C, it was a big `if` statement.  In Swift, we can use optional chaining.

Suppose that `didUpdate` is an optional method.  Calling it on our delegate then looks like this:

```
self.delegate?.didUpdate?()
```

The only difference here is the `?` before the parenthesis.

What this line of code says is basically:

```
if delegate is not nil and if delegate responds to selector "didUpdate"
    call "didUpdate" on delegate
else
    do nothing
```

The other important thing here is that we need to be sure that we're making our reference to the delegate a `weak` reference, which can only be done if our protocol is specified as `@objc`.  In almost every case, the object acting as our delegate is already holding a strong reference to the class that needs the delegate.  If this class also holds a strong reference back to the delegate (which you're currently doing), we've creating a retain cycle.  The memory can never be released without annoying setting each other's reference to the other to be `nil`... and the hard part is often times figuring out when to do that.

So, let's make our protocol be an `@objc` protocol and use a weak reference to our delegate, and then use optional chaining to take care of the optional methods.